# submitting full HTML page to x-www-form-urlencoded as querystring encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I am trying to submit full HTML Page to server but I dont have a form to submit. I am not sure if i am doing it correctly but using javascript I am trying to rebuild a json object {html: htmlPage, fileName: "foo" } into a query string and then submit it to server here is the code I have. when i console str the HTML page doesnt look right. I am using jquery

```
  var htmlPage = $("html").html();



       var str = { html: htmlPage, fileName: "foo" };
var params = jQuery.param( str );



           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '/', true);

xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function () {

    if (this.status === 200) {
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');

        }
        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

        var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {

            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
console.log('in error', e);
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery, then just use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.
This will base64 encode your html, then on the server side you only have to base64 decode it, then use it. And hey the entire html code can't be counted as form-data, it's "text/html".

(updated) Try it, let me know.

```
// javascript
function _upload(html_string)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        data: {html: btoa(html_string), fileName: "foo" },
        success: function(data, textStatus, req){
            console.log(textStatus);
        },
        error: function(req , textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("jqXHR["+textStatus+"]: "+errorThrown);
            console.log('jqXHR.data', req.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer , how come I can send entire html using postman ?

Comment: my sever is taking it variables  x-www-form-urlencoded . no JSON